# Using a constexpr static member of a reference as template argument

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

I'm trying to figure out whether GCC or Clang interpret the C++17 standard differently / wrong here.

This is my code, which does compile using GCC 8, but not using Clang 6:

```
struct BoolHolder {
    constexpr static bool b = true;
};

template<bool b>
class Foo {};

int main() {
    BoolHolder b;
    Foo<b.b> f; // Works

    BoolHolder & br = b;
    Foo<br.b> f2; // Doesn't work
}
```

I wonder why that is. Obviously, `b.b` is a valid constexpr (or the first `Foo<b.b>` wouldn't be valid). Is `br.b` not a valid constexpr? Why? The object or the reference itself should have nothing to do with it, since we're accessing a static constexpr member here, right?

If this is really not valid C++17, should the fact that GCC doesn't even warn me (even though I enabled `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`) be considered a bug?

Comment: FWIW, MSVS and icc also compile.

Comment: I think this is related to the question: with `constexpr int f(int) { return 0;}`, would `f(x)` be a `constexpr` for `int x;`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696686/generic-lambda-and-its-argument-as-constant-expression

Comment: I would not bet that the reference is *not* relevant here. `br`is *not* constexpr and so everything based on `br` is also not constexpr.

Maybe as workaround you could use `BoolHolder::b`, if `BoolHolder` is not constant within this context you might use `decltype`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clang is correct. References are evaluated "eagerly" in constant expressions, so to speak. [expr.const]/2.11:

> An expression `e` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation
>   of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one
>   of the following expressions:
>
> - [...]
> - an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and
>     either
>
>   - it is initialized with a constant expression or
>   - its lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;
> - [...]

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't the `… unless […] it is initialized with a constant expression …` part be true here? Also, should the expression `br.b` really evaluate to an `id-expression`? It's a static member access, thus the object itself is irrelevant?

Comment: `b` is not a constant expression. The object expression is still evaluated even though the result is discarded.

Comment: Sad that it is not interpreted as `BoolHolder::b` first.

Comment: @Jarod42 Would you prefer `f().x` to not evaluate `f()` if `x` is a static data member?

Comment: What does "unless the reference has a preceding initialization" mean?